# i have a issue when use tinymce to embed video

Tags: tinymce

This works for me in the editor but when you submit the post data it encodes certain < and > signs as html entities.

```
<p>
&lt;object height="350" width="425" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/BUQ4kRw-P3o&feature;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"&gt;
<param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/BUQ4kRw-P3o&feature;" />
&lt;/object&gt;
</p>
```

Everything I've tried in terms of the extra init parameters won't get rid of this. Any tips?
Thanks so much

Comment: have a lok at the tinymce init parameter entity_encoding